# Как убрать нули в дробной части?

Tags: python, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Как сделать так, чтобы:

```
3.00 стало 3
4.20 стало 4.2
1.5600 стало 1.56
12.345000000 стало 12.345
```

и так далее...
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, использовать спецификатор формата `g`

```
print(f'{3.140:g}')
```

Если какие-то числа будут в научной нотации выводиться `(3.14E-2)`, то можно использовать `f`-спецификатор, но обрезать конечные нули, и потом точку (`rstrip`)

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove(x: float):
    return str(x).rstrip('0.')

print(remove(3.00))
print(remove(4.20))
print(remove(1.5600))
print(remove(12.345000000))
```

```
3
4.2
1.56
12.345
```

Comment: У тебя remove(3.00) возвращает 3.0, а не 3.

Comment: @ArseniyRybasov, извиняюсь, невнимательно прочитал. Поправил код для этого теста.